# Time zone automatically reset

Tags: time-zones

When I set an event in the S Planner under Pacific Time (GMT -7) and then later try to edit it, the event opens under London/Dublin (GMT +1). How can I fix this? I have set the time zone to Pacific.

(Galaxy Ace 11x)